# How to pass private parameters to multiple instances of node?

Tags: ros, namespace, ros-kinetic, getparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have created a package containing a rospy node that I wish to be able to launch from arbitrary other packages with custom arguments with each launch

eg. myex.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
foo = rospy.get_param("foo")          
print str(foo)
```

In a launch file somewhere else:

```
<launch>
<node pkg="min_ex" name="node_name" type="myex.py" output="screen">
    <param name="foo" type="int" value="5"/>
</node>
</launch>
```

This always returns
KeyError: 'foo'

Adding "~" to the beginning of the param name in both or either of the launch or .py does not make a difference.

rosparam list shows me that foo is being published on mylib1/foo

So How can I get the node to access the parameter without having to know about the namespace in which it has been launched? I want to be able to create many instantiations of the same node using different parameters.

Code example to show my problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
foo = rospy.get_param("~foo")
print str(foo)
```

launch file:

```
<launch>
<node pkg="min_ex" name="node_name" type="myex.py" output="screen">
    <param name="~foo" type="int" value="5"/>
</node>
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/337741/how-to-pass-private-parameters-to-multiple-instances-of-node?/) by [LukeAI](https://answers.ros.org/users/38953/lukeai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2019-11-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-19**:
re: MWE in 'mini workspace': we don't need a workspace. The two files are sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The thing I was missing was that it is necessary to init the node in order to access private params. eg.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
rospy.init_node("some_name")
foo = rospy.get_param("~foo")
print str(foo)
```

---

Originally posted by [LukeAI](https://answers.ros.org/users/38953/lukeai/) with karma: 131 on 2019-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In rospy , private parameters use the `~` symbol.

http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Parameter%20Server#CA-3f15412c75f9c3ecdd015c4e59b4927fea7946cb_3

Ei.

```
  foo = rospy.get_param("~foo")
```

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2019-11-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LukeAI](https://answers.ros.org/users/38953/lukeai/) on 2019-11-19**:
Thanks for response, I have read that page, unfortunately it doesn't work. I have produced a minimal working example that illustrates the point

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-19**:\

> Adding "~" to the beginning of the param name in both or either of the launch or .py does not make a difference.

you are *only* supposed to prefix `~` to the name of the parameter in your `rospy.get_param(..)` call. Not to the name in the `.launch` file.

The fact that you make the `param` element a child of the `node` element already makes it a private parameter.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-19**:
You show this in your MWE:

> ```
> #!/usr/bin/env python
> ```

```
import rospy
foo = rospy.get_param("~foo")
print str(foo)
```

this is not a node (as you don't call `rospy.init_node(..)`), so `rospy.get_param(..)` will also not be relative to a node. Hence the problem accessing the parameter.

**Comment by [LukeAI](https://answers.ros.org/users/38953/lukeai/) on 2019-11-19**:
yeah that got it!